# What are those sensors on the forward A321neo fuselage?

Tags: airbus-a320, feature-identification, sensors

[image]

What are those sensors on the forward (Airbus) A321neo fuselage? If it helps, this is WOW air's TF-DTR.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The probe on the left is a TAT (Total Air Temperature) probe and the device on the right is an Ice Detector.

From this website: [UTC Aerospace Systems](https://utcaerospacesystems.com/product_gallery/air-data-systems/) (Total Air Temp)

From this website:[UTC Aerospace Systems](https://utcaerospacesystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Ice-Detector-Model-0871ND.pdf) (Ice Detector)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

And the yellow antenna behind the Ice Detector is the ATC (Air Traffic Control) antenna.[image]